# How to get facebook user id without calling FB.getLoginStatus and promting user to grand access for public information

Tags: facebook

I am developing asp.net web site to be facebook application.

I am trying to make "Facebook Like Gate" to promt user Like my page before he can see the application. For example https://www.facebook.com/AvonProductsInc?sk=app_188308831197082.

The problem is that application above does not aks me for permission to get my basic information, but i have to promt user give me such permission before i can use following code to get user_id and check wether he has already Liked my page:

```
function checkFBlike() {

    //FB.login
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

        var r = response;

        if (response.status == "connected") {

            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var page_id = "341342102543433"; //341342102543433            168619489865949
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + page_id + "and uid=" + user_id;
            var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

            the_query.wait(function (rows) {

                if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                    //jQuery("#container_like").show();
                    fbLikeGateHide();
                    //here you could also do some ajax and get the content for a "liker" instead of simply showing a hidden div in the page.

                }
                else {

                    //and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
                }
            });


        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, but not connected to the app
            showFbLogin();  //display Facebook Login button 

        }
        else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    });


}

function showFbLogin(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        var r=response;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to be like the avon app (specifically a page tab application) You should look at the `signed_request` parameter coming from the HTTP POST that Facebook does when your page is a canvas app.  You really don't need to do any client side checks.

For more information about the signed_request, see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Thanks for responce. But after I added following code into my web.config:

Comment: Finally I solved my issue - the question was in redirecting in my web site.